# Search a sentence based on keyword and return the word that meets the keyword

Tags: android, regex, string, kotlin

I need to get the URL link of a certain company then do some processing of that URL.
Currently I'm trying to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to get the word, but not getting as per my requirement.

```
val p: Pattern = Pattern.compile("abc.com")
val m: Matcher = p.matcher("Hi, welcome to ABC Website. test-page.abc.com/?12345 link to your profile.")
if (m.find()) {
    AppLog.d("UnitTest", "Found : ${m.group()}")
} else {
    AppLog.d("UnitTest", "Not found")
}
```

Running this, I'm getting this output

> Found : abc.com

Is there are way for me to get the whole link instead? Any Regex can be use to in order for me to get this?

> Found : test-page.abc.com/?12345

Comment: Could something like `\S*abc\.com\S*` be helpfull?

Comment: Yes, this regex works. Put as answer and I'll accept as this is the first one that answer my question. Thanks @JvdV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you could think about something like:

```
\S*abc\.com\S*
```

This would extract a substring that holds `abc.com` but include all leading and trailing characters other than whitespace characters.